# Generar PDF a partir de un reporte XML sin usar JRXML por cada reporte utilizando JasperReport

Tags: java, oracle, jasper-reports, ireport

Herramientas: Java, Maven, Oracle , JasperReport, ireport, itext.

Escenario actual: Actualmente genero mis reportes pdf(Al hacer submit) a partir de un archivo xml(creado manualmente) que contiene los parámetros de entrada y la consulta sql, se construye el archivo jrxml(creado de forma manual en ireport).

Problema: Son miles de reportes, por lo que no sería factible hacer un jrxml manualmente con ireports para cada reporte y luego generar el pdf.

Escenario ideal: Generar el pdf a partir del archivo XML. sin usar un jrxml por cada reporte, o usar un solo archivo jrxml genérico para todos los reportes.

Agradecería que alguien me guiara en lo que requiero y como hacer esto en lo expuesto en "escenario ideal". Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Con los datos que das es bastante difícil. ¿Cómo de parecidos son los informes? Si son muy diferentes... ya sabes. En iReport puedes aplicar lógica (se muestra / no se muestra) según criterios de entrada (tu xml). Otra opción sería que te picaras una clasesita basandote a itext y que te haga el trabajo. Es más o menos lo mismo - según criterio de entrada hago una u otra cosa.

Comment: Entiendo, soy un novato en esto, la verdad es que tengo limitado el acceso a algunas clases, pero en si el escenario actual es ese, el xml tiene los parametros, la query y la persistencia. En cuanto a lo de iText, voy a buscar en internet, si puedes guiarme al respecto te agradeceria.